# BURNINATE the bugs tag

Tags: discussion

There is currently no real reason for the [bugs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag! I suggest that it die slowly in an explosion.

Comment: Need to find something I can ask about [this game.](http://appshopper.com/education/bugs-2)

Comment: Should this not be added as an answer to the community clean-up question which has been collecting the other Burninated tags?

Comment: @shanodin Shouldn't that be a duplicate then?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz that tag could be potentially misused by users. Better something like `bugs-ios` or `bugs-the-game` or... something...

Comment: Isn't this question older than [Please, blacklist the bugs tags](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8131/4797)? The duplicate closure should probably be the other way around.

Comment: @galacticninja Question age doesn't matter that much. And I saw this one after I already responded to the other. It's six of one, half dozen of the other.